# SyntaxError: expected ':' despite having a colon in the specified place

Tags: python, syntax, compiler-errors

I've been trying to make a small journal program, and whenever I try to run it, the program errors out with

```
SyntaxError: expected ':'
```

The program should run as normal, allowing the user to write into their journal. What happens is that the code quits out saying there's a syntax error on the else statement. I've tried to rewrite the code to check if I've missed something, but everything seems correct.

```
currentDate = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


f = open(currentDate, "w")
    print("Write what you want to add into your journal, and it'll be saved when you hit enter.")
    f.write(input())
    f.close()
    print("Are you done? (press 'y' if you are)")
    userfinished = input()
    if userfinished == "y":
        print("Alright then.")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("You can now read the file you've created in your operating system's file explorer (in built reader coming soon).")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Goodbye.")
        sys.exit()
    else userfinished == "n":
        print("Alright, keep on writing.")
        f = open(currentDate, "a")
        f.write(input())
```

Comment: Typo, `else userfinished == "n":` should be `elif userfinished == "n":`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a syntax error on your else statement. For `else` there's no condition to be met because it implies ***ALL other conditions not specified in previous ifs***.

You could do

```
if userfinished == "y":
    ...
else: 
    ...
```

or,

```
if userfinished == "y":
    ...
elif userfinished == "n":
    ...
```

Comment: `elif if` is not correct.